# Fragment stays in layout after detached and activity destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragmenttransaction

I have a very interesting case. I have enabled "don't keep activities" option in the developer options menu on Android. 
Now, when I start the application, everything is fine, the application starts normally.

Later, when I press the home button and exit the app, I see that activity's onDestroy(), fragment's onDestroy() and onDetach() callbacks are called. But when I start the app again, the fragment's onCreate() and onCreateView() callbacks are called, **even I haven't added the fragment yet**.

And when app's framework is initialized and it is the first time to add the fragments, I see the fragment is still there inside the layout. I know that because the fragment object below must be null at first but it is not. It is same fragment that is removed after I closed the app before.

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(rootFragmentLayoutId);
```

Normally, the code above returns null at first init, but when I enable "don't keep activities" option, it is not null anymore.

Is this some kind of bug with the developer options configuration? If not how is this even possible? I am afraid of our users having problems because of this problem.

Comment: Ok, i resolved the problem by removing all the fragments left on activity create. But I still suspect this is some kind of bug with Android so I will leave this question here for further comments.

Comment: does your fragment use setRetainInstance()?

Comment: @МаксимПетлюк Good question. But I could not find any code with setRetainInstance(). In addition, fragment's onDestroy() is called so I can say that property is not set.